# Error: expression cannot be used as a function. How to remove this?

Tags: c++, compare, qsort

I am using this structure

```
    struct box
    {
        int h,w,d;
    };
    int compare (const void *a, const void * b)
    {
        return  ((*(box *)b).d * (*(box *)b).w) – ((*(box *)a).d * (*(box *)a).w); // error is showing in this line
    }
    box rot[3*n];
    qsort (rot, n, sizeof(rot[0]), compare);
```

and I am trying qsort
but showing error expression cannot be used as a function in

Comment: That character `–` in the middle of the long line is not a minus sign, but an n-dash. Once that is fixed, your code [compiles for me](http://rextester.com/HDKJ89705)

Comment: You'd probably have a much easier time figuring out your error if you wrote readable code. Condensing everything down to one statement buys you nothing.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thanks it is also worked for me, but how you detect that?

Comment: `how you detect that?` The compiler [told me](http://rextester.com/POQM99024).

Comment: Just use `std::sort`. It's a **lot** faster.

Comment: always start from fixing **first** error from compiler

Comment: Local variables can improve readability and cost nothing. Example: `const box& l = *(box*) a; const box& r = *(box*) b; return r.d * r.w - l.d * l.w;`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the minus operator in the return line which should be `-` instead of `–`

another problem when defining the array `rot` which should contain elements of type **`struct box`** instead of `box` as there is **NO** `typedef` in the structure block

So you are in front of two possibilities to make it work either you add a tag `box` for the structure `box` :

```
typedef struct box
{
    int h,w,d;
} box;
```

or simply add the word `struct` in the definition of the array `rot` and in compare function like that (before every `box` word):

```
int compare (const void *a, const void * b)
{
    return  ((*(struct box *)b).d * (*(struct box *)b).w) - ((*(struct box *)a).d * (*(struct box *)a).w);
}
```

and

```
struct box rot[3*n];
```

Comment: This is C++, the `typedef` is not required.